# Malware checks for hwid

Tags: cryptography, c#

Recently, I received malware executable to analyse - it's written in C#, and it's packed/obfuscated with unknown tool, so I started analysis from analysing it's traffic - what it's sending and receiving - and I've found out that after exe starts, it downloads `attackerwebsite.com/main.xml` and that file looks for me like hwid lists, where malware should operate, because when I open it on my pc, it's showing me error, but when my friend starts it on his attacked machine, it's executing in background. Part of transferred file looks like this:

```
RFx8jwcYx7BRG4THW7VnxNpJngjku4JGQbzeoiKHl0jHjR+Q5eE56U/ahuvvVnGCTMvRlmZXoGhplAKYHWPHpIzCCJygwpQfhJzBDG7R6z8=
qsb2Wt5tVZCp8oL0QhZPQkIgAgh4tZCdQZspAmqZIjU=
M0d+iQi3D2GAdPOQVSGDmMEIgm+3CIr7gsAxkdeMMhDP7SNdGy1LsJH8BEYDyxRMOdfoz/eXWKN/7g8w09Q7gA==
9qHMzL3YxPjH0twK1iu8RWFDqmgYBQyeyEt/h08i8pIb7ZcznKY03JXxp+Es66h/thc1UpsPnKcvboOWhS2ymQ==
QIlTv37HbTvftGLgruLi9dJSZv5yU1JIaArSu8i24kcS6FOPGXOhnXax6gYHKgZt
4x+2Y4l9xILsm28ldTCoGAZB/XuhWO7S0PQfXpEpnTi887J1qA8UAm5FAlXZnB9w+1GlBkVopzQsPdrVe3QI4w==
t2UY+j7lcKoh+nywSDVGVcP0DjBfid2bOUUqgV5sJndGARiSRS5BDg4Nsle2fpT4AAXDs8fMWKR96876u7Dnig==
WVomGVrQ4RyffNLyn8c2lnDBXnizW0A3HYMNSqpN1eUwE/xh4UpMXypmd75kLkPh
lZV56hvraWQSETIrJhMrpD2yBb4tplZswT4ws9Lb5rkUMtoAl6fI7MymLhC794HQmTqlWIbFKnlh0K4rhYXnGQ==
RG+VLzAW8lKdhKdHDbiXeMge2EPOove2tj0Qm59IIm4YSsggX1m1rsNwFY4EL9y1//+OlXUGECZLr3WskKcDkQ==
caaijfTyoXkqPqboAX+TXNs22go6Vir33pa1GxOgpLiQLZRDeSpVJjJ6pJf4igUkkj75cgYzYgV8c4OGXxaJnQ==
P0UtlPzInfxktvzGsdxG1QpFl6q/VkrpRtU/+TiGX5UmhiMLAvz4YtRn785kUJkbnbjm1N2vdA4w2Bu3ew6sLQ==
lP9Jw0gVw8Hd+515tPx09ya3Q5geR202ucS4DI7R1ghFWX89+HT9ASqVv5ynST8BE7rOJJMFHx8BFx2HjLMmdQ==
fnHXjjdAO5I3+FeKtvtwyn2JlF+k4AiynLH5XK0cLy8fsugEHKubmleS4YRA74Gg
x/3gRboIOcqV/a5IOEkts1881jf3huUCDLrkZDSrr2TJ86rG6buwmKrsJMZyUXBg
2uXpW+PXdbskPABxoyvVbuaYuVOgnWKsv/eMs1UBTQo=
```

I've noticed that this is probably hwid encoded in some way, because of padding with equality mark - look at length of lines - there are 4 fixed line lengths - **44**, **64**, **88**, and **108** - can anybody help me in identifying that hashing/encryption algorithm? Where can I start? Analysing executable would be pain in the a** unless I unpack it.

Answer (score 3):

It's base64. One entry per line. Entries look like they're padded to 0x10. So after base64 decoding the data is probably encrypted by a block cipher with 128-bit block size. Maybe AES. At this stage you probably need to analyze the executable in order to get the plaintext back.